# Getting error when remove register with SQL-ALCHEMY

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am removing a row to my database connected with SQL-Alchemy, but I am receiving the following error:

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
2020-06-12T20:37:21.822757+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise exception
2020-06-12T20:37:21.822873+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.NoneType' is not mapped
```

What is strange is that I have been able to use the exact same question with another table and it worked great.
Here is my Python code:

```
@app.route('/deleteleads/<solicitudes_id>/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def deleteleads(solicitudes_id):
    my_data = Data.query.get(solicitudes_id)
    db.session.delete(my_data)
    db.session.commit()
    flash("¡Lead eliminado satisfactoriamente!")

    return redirect(url_for('show_leads'))
```

And here are my models:

```
class Leads(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'solicitudes'
    solicitudes_id = db.Column(db.BIGINT, primary_key=True)
    tipouso = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))
    tipoauto = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))
    credito = db.Column(db.BOOLEAN)
    entidadcrediticia = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))
    id_auto = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255), db.ForeignKey('autos.id_auto'))
    id_user = db.Column(db.BIGINT, db.ForeignKey('usuarios.id_user'))
    fecha = db.Column(db.DATE)
    canalinput = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))
    ciudadcompra = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))
    hora = db.Column(db.TIME(255))


    def __init__(self, solicitudes_id, tipouso, tipoauto, credito, entidadcrediticia, id_auto, id_user, fecha, canalinput, ciudadcompra, hora):
        self.solicitudes_id = solicitudes_id
        self.tipouso = tipouso
        self.tipoauto = tipoauto
        self.credito = credito
        self.entidadcrediticia = entidadcrediticia
        self.id_auto = id_auto
        self.id_user = id_user
        self.fecha = fecha
        self.canalinput = canalinput
        self.ciudadcompra = ciudadcompra
        self.hora = hora
```

Hope you can help me to solve this problem.

Thank you,

Jonathan Prieto

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was not using the correct table:

````
def deleteleads(solicitudes_id):
    my_data = Leads.query.get(solicitudes_id)
    db.session.delete(my_data)
    db.session.commit()
    flash("¡Lead eliminado satisfactoriamente!")

    return redirect(url_for('show_leads'))```
My table is Leads in this case, not Data.
````